# How to call Toast msg from LWC to Visualforce page (Toast message in VF page)

Tags: visualforce, lightning-web-components, lightning-experience, toast, sforce

I have been searching for **Toast Message** on the **VF** page. Because I have called my **LWC** inside one **Vf** page. it is working fine but the **Toast message** is not accessible or we can say visible on the VF page.

So I have been searching about this but got nothing helpful. But thanks to the salesforce community I have found a way to call all Toast msg from Lwc to the Vf page in two line code snippet which will work on every vf page (This answer has been given by Bartosz Śliwiński ).
Below is the Answer for this.

Comment: Hi and welcome to SFSE. Please read [How to Ask](/help/how-to-ask) and perhaps take the [tour] to understand how Q&As are handled on this site. You should frame the question and then provide a separate self-answer (in the "Your Answer" box, below) in this sort of situation. Better still, add an alternative answer to [this existing Q&A](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/303367/how-can-i-show-a-lwc-toastevent-message-in-visualforce). Nice to see you cite the original author of the solution.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I show a LWC ToastEvent message in Visualforce?](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/303367/how-can-i-show-a-lwc-toastevent-message-in-visualforce)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Toast mesage alert for visualforce page](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/231252/toast-mesage-alert-for-visualforce-page)

Comment: Thank you so much @PhilW for the warm welcome & the guidance .
Will keep this all in mind for future Q&A.

Comment: When I say "answer," I mean the one that you two (@PhilW & @Tushar Jadav) suggested. You know, I'm not sure if those answers resolved my issue or not, but they definitely are long and incomprehensible to me. hence the solution I've been provided (originally given by Bartosz Śliwiński) is more practical and simple to use.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [ShowToastEvent notification is not displayed in LWC](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/267571/showtoastevent-notification-is-not-displayed-in-lwc)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use this code snippet inside the script tag,and above the `$Lightning.use` code that's it nothing else  :

```
**document.addEventListener('lightning__showtoast', event => {
        sforce.one.showToast(event.toastAttributes);
    });**
```

More briefly if needed:

```
<script>
    document.addEventListener('lightning__showtoast', event => {
        sforce.one.showToast(event.toastAttributes);
    });
    $Lightning.use("c:YourOutApp", () => {
        ...
    });
</script>
```

Comment: It is good to include explanation as to what the solution is doing, not just the code. Including the citation of the original author would be good (like you had done). It also makes sense to include this answer as an answer in one or both of the existing questions, IMHO.

Comment: For all those who need more brief about the Answer here's the original answer link:
(https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/267571/showtoastevent-notification-is-not-displayed-in-lwc).

i am still in the learning phase so can't be the right person to say brief about the answer I have given.

Comment: Again thank you @PhilW for suggesting important things to me so that viewers can understand more clearly.

Comment: Ah! So the answer is already on this site. In which case this is definitely a duplicate (though I understand there was a lot of "old" information included that you needed to wade through).